# How to smooth camera when falling in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am working on an endless jumper that turns into a faller type game.  The camera on the way up is SUPER smooth, but on the way down it is extremely jerky.

I am not sure how to make it just follow the player with script and not jerk.

Camera going up:

```
 float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp(currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY, Time.deltaTime * 10);
 transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera, transform.position.z);
```

Camera going down:

```
 float newHeightOfCamera = Mathf.Lerp(currentCameraHeight, playerHeightY - fallCamera, Time.deltaTime);
 transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera - cameraFallLocation, transform.position.z);
```

On the way down the player goes to the top of the screen and is set to a fixed speed.

```
 pc.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, fallSpeed);  //changes falling speed
```

Comment: Notice how in the up you use a time frame of `Time.deltaTime` * 10. And in the down you use a time frame of `Time.deltaTime` alone. Try multiplying it as well

Comment: Can you explain what is `fallCamera` and `cameraFallLocation`? Also are these values chaning in time?

Comment: And where is called your code samples? On Update both or in other places?

Answer (score 0):

I am still waiting for response to my comments, but for 90% your problem can be solved very easy with just moving all your code samples from `Update` to `LateUpdate` (or even from `FixedUpdate` to `LateUpdate`). In most cases that is enough. But still, we would need to know more details to be sure it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I took a break from this game as it was frustrating.  Here is what I came up with

This was for the falling.  I didn't end up need the camera to catch up I just wanted it to be still.

```
        float newHeightOfCamera = playerHeightY - fallCamera;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, newHeightOfCamera - cameraFallLocation, transform.position.z);
```

fallCamera was the location of the camera.  I wanted the character to be at the bottom of the screen when going up and at the top of the screen when going down.